# Combobox updating ItemsSource when it should not

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a combobox that looks like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbGender"
            DisplayMemberPath="Value"
            ItemsSource="{x:Static patientObjects:Gender.GenderList}"
            SelectedIndex="0"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Encounter.Patient.Gender,
                                    Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedValuePath="Id"
            StaysOpenOnEdit="True" />
```

This all works fine for normal use.  However, when I load Encounter.Patient.Gender from my database, then clear the value out.  The next use of the combobox has overwritten the the top item in my Gender.GenderList with the value loaded from the database.  (In my repro example, Unknown is overwritten with Male).

My GenderList is an ObserverableCollection of static gender properties.  Each of those properties is backed by a static readonly gender field.

Because the backing fields are readonly, my guess is that the collection is having a reference updated somehow.  But I can't figure out how it could be done with this binding...

**Any guesses?**

Update: I tried the following with no effect:

1. Removing SelectedIndex and SelectedValuePath
2. Adding an event to the GenderList collection's collection changed (did not fire).
3. Removing the TwoWay mode off the SelectedItem
4. Changing the Gender.GenderList to be a `ReadOnlyObserveableCollection`.

Comment: Do you get the same thing happening when you get rid of `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedIndex`? Usually you only use one of the three selection methods (`SelectedIndex`, `SelectedItem`, and `SelectedValue`/`SelectedValuePath`), and I've seen problems when you use more than one method to set the selected item at the same time.

Comment: @Rachel- thanks for the tip.  Alas, it did not fix the issue I am seeing.

Comment: Why do you have Mode=TwoWay if the backing fields are readonly?  Do you override Equals?

Comment: @Blam- yes I do.  But I don't think I need that.  I took the "TwoWay" mode out and the bug still happens (but everything else works fine).

Comment: I would debug calls to Equals and see if you notice something off.